# Simplifying Equivalences in Łukasiewicz Logic

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

I am working on an inference system for infinite valued [Łukasiewicz logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lukasiewicz_logic), using standard MV-algebras.

As a pre-processing step, I would like to perform (non-exhaustive) simplification of formulae.  So I am wondering what simplifying equivalences hold in the algebra of this logic.  I know that the usual [lattice axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29) hold:

$$a \lor a = a$$
$$a \land a = a$$
$$ \vdots$$
$$ \text{etc.}$$

The absorption laws listed above would are good examples of simplifying formulae.

Anybody know of some other good simplifying algebraic identities for Łukasiewicz logic?

Comment: Any examples of formulas in particular that you want to simplify?

Answer (score 2):

For a convenient set of identities, have you checked the usual axioms of MV-algebras?  For normal forms, have you had a look at McNaughton's theorem?  The answer to these questions may be found in the work by Antonio Di Nola and by Daniele Mundici.  Have you checked the proof-theoretic approach proposed by George Metcalfe?

Comment: Well, I want to simplify expressions prior to converting to McNaughton Normal Forms.  Yeah, I've looked at the usual axioms, but honestly apart from absorption rules it doesn't appear that there are many good candidates for simplification rules, so I was hoping an expert would chime in.  As for Metcalfe's stuff: my decision procedure involves solving SAT problems over McNaughton Normal Forms, so I've pretty much married myself to using semantics over proof theory...

Answer (score 1):

An infinite valued logic on [0, 1] with max(x, y)=(x$\lor$y), min(x, y)=(x$\land$y), (1-x)=$\lnot$x has the same theorems as a three-valued logic on {0, 1/2, 1} with max for $\lor$, min for $\land$, and (1-x) for $\lnot$.  So, we just need to check the three-valued cases for any proposed simplifying equivalence.  See Walker and Nguyen's *A First Course in Fuzzy Logic*, the section on the logical aspects of fuzzy sets, for an outline of a proof.  Unfortunately, I don't know if we have a similar situation for the richer structure you've referenced.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. In Łukasiewicz logic a → b = min(1,1-a+b); you can define a + b := ¬a → b.  It is not generally true that (a+a+a) → (a+a) (for instance, where a = 1/3), however in a three valued logic that would be a tautology.  I'm now a little skeptical that your source is treating the same fuzzy logic I'm studying.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that strong disjunction "+" isn't similar in 3-valued and infinite-valued logic.  That said, for any formula which uses *only* $\lor$, $\land$, and $\lnot$, the above still should apply.

Answer (score 0):

To give a few that I've come up with, we have the absorption rules I mentioned:

$$ a \land a = a$$
$$ a \lor a = a$$

We also have some other common lattice rules:

$$ 0 \lor a = a$$
$$ 0 \land a = 0$$
$$ 1 \land a = a$$
$$ 1 \lor a = 1 $$

In fact, all of these can be seen as instances of the general absorption pattern (particular to Łukasiewicz logic):

$$ (a \oplus b) \lor a = (a \oplus b) $$
$$ (a \oplus b) \land a = a $$

There's also double negation:
$$ \neg\neg a = a $$

Here are some simplifying implication rules:
$$ a \to a = 1$$
$$ a \to 0 = \neg a $$
$$ \neg a \to \neg b = b \to a $$